# JCL SORT SQZ shift left using build

Tags: sorting, mainframe, jcl

I have 2 input files. I merged them using JOINKEY. The first input file countains a record count (lenght of 10 with leading zeroes).
The second file, is just comma separated fields between double quote (ex ''xxxx'',''yyyy'',etc).

The problem I got is I want to get rid of the leading zeroes from the records count of the first input file.

My count is 0000000012, I will like to have 12.

I don't understand how to handle it with SQZ function since it will be a variable lenght.  How can we handle it in the OUTREC BUILD since it will not be a fix length of 10 anymore but a variable length if I use SQZ function?

Thanks for your help.

Here is the JCL:

```
//SORT100 EXEC PGM=SORT                                       
//*                                                            
//SORTJNF1 DD * 
 Counter written records:           0000000012                                                               
//SORTJNF2 DD 
   DSN=INPUT.WITHOUT.COUNT,DISP=SHR                                            
//SORTOUT DD DSN=OUTPUT.WITH.COUNT, 
//        DISP= 
    (,CATLG),RECFM=FB,LRECL=130,DATACLAS=DCPRXTP    

//SYSIN    DD *                                                
 SORT FIELDS=COPY                                              
 JOINKEYS FILE=F1,FIELDS=(131,8,A),SORTED,NOSEQCK              
 JOINKEYS FILE=F2,FIELDS=(131,8,A),SORTED,NOSEQCK              
 REFORMAT FIELDS=(F2:1,80,F1:30,10)                            
 OUTREC BUILD=(1,80,81,10,C'," "',36X)                         
//JNF1CNTL DD *                                                
 INREC OVERLAY=(131:SEQNUM,8,ZD)                              
//JNF2CNTL DD *                                                
 INREC OVERLAY=(131:SEQNUM,8,ZD)                              
//*                                                            
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                         
//
```

Comment: I am able to suppress the leading zeroes.  The only problem I got is to go writting after it since the length of the counter is variable.

Comment: Would SHIFT=LEFT,PREBLANK=C'0'  help? It looked vaguely useful here

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.iceg200/ljarjd.htm

Comment: I used //SYSIN    DD *                          
 SORT FIELDS=COPY                        
 OUTREC OVERLAY=(30,10,UFF,M10,LENGTH=10,
     1:1,10,JFY=(SHIFT=LEFT),70X)      The problem is how I determine where I can write after I put the counter in the file since it is a variable length ?   I was able to have 12 in the counter file but when I merged it with the second file, I don't know how to determine what is the lenght of the counter since it is variable